# MKMapView overlapping MKAnnotations only allow showing two of the callouts

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I have three `MKPointAnnotation` objects that are added in the exact same coordinates to an `MKMapView` and they are each given a unique title.

```
MKPointAnnotation *a1 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
a1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.875684, -122.656254);
a1.title = @"Title 1";
[self.mapView addAnnotation:a1];

MKPointAnnotation *a2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
a2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.875684, -122.656254);
a2.title = @"Title 2";
[self.mapView addAnnotation:a2];

MKPointAnnotation *a3 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
a3.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.875684, -122.656254);
a3.title = @"Title 3";
[self.mapView addAnnotation:a3];
```

When adding them to the map, normally you can just tap the annotation, then tap again and again to cycle through the overlapped pins. However, when there are more than two, it seems you are limited to only cycling through two of the annotations, even though there are three that are overlapping. `Title 1` is never shown:

[image]

This seems like an `MKMapView` bug to me, but has anyone else experienced this before and found a way around it?

Comment: Handling MKMapView Annotation Pins on the Same Coordinate with Swift https://blog.stormid.com/2015/10/mkmapview-pins-swift/

Comment: @KosukeOgawa This wouldn't be helpful as our app must have pins placed at the exact coordinates.

Comment: Ohh I get it. In iOS 11 and later, You can use `MKAnnotationView. clusteringIdentifier` ... Good Luck! https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CLhj.gif

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this works as you describe and it does seem like a bug (or at least I couldn't find any relevant documentation).

One solution (workaround) would be to manage the two annotations that the mapView can handle by yourself. Then, when the user selects (or deselects) an annotation, you can swap the one that was just deselected to the 3rd one. Something like:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        mapView.removeAnnotation(view.annotation!)
        mapView.addAnnotation(a1)
    }
}
```

I hope this makes sense. Good luck!