# zIndex does not work on ANY element in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I already saw that there were posts where you were trying to solve zIndex defects of react native maps for markers. But it does not work on ANYTHING in react native maps, including Polygon, Polyline. Is there any solution to solve this huge problem?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191457/react-native-maps-markers-prop-zindex-doesnt-work-correctly-in-ios-11.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-native-maps Marker's prop zIndex doesn't work correctly in iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191457/react-native-maps-markers-prop-zindex-doesnt-work-correctly-in-ios-11)

Comment: No, it does not. Because it is just POSSIBLE solution and only for markers. As I said, I need to use zIndex for polygon and polyline too.

Answer (score 0):

try to do this :

```
 <MapView
      //ref={_map}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      }}
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, // <-- add this style to map
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
      }}
      //provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      >
      <Marker
        coordinate={{latitude: LATITUDE,longitude: LONGITUDE,}}
        title={'itle'}
      />
    </MapView>
    <View style={{marginVertical: 20, flexDirection: 'row',}}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {}}
        style={[styles.bubble, styles.button]}>
        <Text>Press me</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
```